# Extracting parameters from JavaScript include tag using a Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently trying to parse parameters from a path to a JavaScript file (inside a script tag). At the moment I know which parameters I expect to be there but instead of looking for the expected params I would rather like to just extract all params given.

Example of the script tag which includes a JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://url/widget.js?param1=A&param2=bb></script>
```

At the moment I'm just doing this (seperately for each parameter):

```
jQuery('script').each(function() {
    var script = this;
    if (!script.src) {
        return;
    }    
    var matchKey = script.match(/https\:\/\/url\/widget\.js\?param1=([A-Z]+)/);
    if (matchKey) {
        oSettings.param1 = matchKey[1];
    }
}
```

So what I need is a regex that extracts both the name of the parameter and the value from the included sript.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Do you want to parse parameters from a Javascript file, or from a _path to_ a Javascript file?

Comment: I was not making my point very clear, thanks. I want to parse parameters from the url to the javascript file inside the script tag. The reason why I'm doing this is because this little bit of javascript code is supposed to build a widget on the corresponding website and I don't want the user to add too many code in different places. I'm just trying to keep all parameters where they belong to (even if there's technically no use of writing it like GET params in javascript context - right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tested function works:

```js
function parse_query_vars(text)
{ // Extract name=value pairs from URL query string.
    // Empty object to store name, value pairs.
    var qvars = {},
    // Capture non-empty query string in $1.
        re_q = /\?([^#]+)/, // From '?' up to '#' or EOS.
    // Capture variable name in $1 and value in $2.
        re_nv = /([^=]+)=([^&]*)(?:&(amp;)?|$)/gi,
    // Match array for query string and va=val pairs.
        m =  text.match(re_q),
    // Query string plucked from URL
        q = '';
    // If there is a query string, copy to q var.
    if (m) q = m[1];
    while (m = re_nv.exec(q)) {
        qvars[m[1]] = m[2];
    }
    return qvars; // Return results in object
}
```

It first extracts any query string from the URL, then iteratively parses out name=value pairs and returns the results in an object. It handles name value pairs separated by either `&` or `&amp;` and works if the URL has a `#fragment` following the query.

Comment: Works pretty well so far! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [this](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm/), or [this](http://www.idealog.us/2006/06/javascript_to_p.html), or [this](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx).

They're not all regex solutions, but then you don't necessarily need a regex. That was a detail that could probably have been left out of the question.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't actually tested)

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"), i = scripts.length;
var reMatch = /https\:\/\/url\/widget\.js/, path;
// find the correct script
do {
    path = scripts[i--].src;
}
while (!reMatch.test(path));

var map = {}, pairs = path.substring(path.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&"), atoms;
i = pairs.length;
// extract the name-value pairs
while (i--) {
    atoms = pairs[i].split("=");
    map[decodeURIComponent(atoms[0])] = decodeURIComponent(atoms[1]);
}
```